# Select a string enclosed by specific delimiters and containing a specific value

Tags: sql-server, xml, string

I have a SQL Server table that stores xml tags in a varchar field and I would like the select statement to return the entire node from each row that contains a specific value. For example:

```
1. <tag1><tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "fghij"></tag2></tag1>
2. <tag1><tag2 value1 = "hfdgd" value2 = "fgytyhij"></tag2></tag1>
3. <tag1><tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "ettyy"></tag2></tag1>
4. <tag1><tag2 value1 = "qwere" value2 = "mnbvb"></tag2></tag1>
```

I want to search term to be "abcde" and I want the select statement to return:

```
<tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "fghij">
<tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "ettyy">
```

I can use PATINDEX to find the location of the pattern that I am searching for. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to find the closest occurrences of '<' and '>' to the search string and return the entire string enclosed with '<' and '>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now work a LOT better. I was missing the @SearchVal in my first posting.

```
declare @TheStrings table(SomeVal varchar(max))

insert @TheStrings values
                              ('<tag1><tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "fghij"></tag2></tag1>')
,('<tag1><tag1a value="asdf"></tag1a><tag2 value11 = "abcde" value3="qwer" value2 = "wow"></tag2></tag1>')

declare @SearchVal varchar(10) = 'abcde'

select 
    SomeVal
    , SUBSTRING(SomeVal, len(SomeVal) - charindex('<', reverse(SomeVal), charindex(reverse(@SearchVal), reverse(SomeVal))) + 1, charindex('>', SUBSTRING(SomeVal, len(SomeVal) - charindex('<', reverse(SomeVal), charindex(reverse(@SearchVal), reverse(SomeVal))) + 1, 100)))
from @TheStrings
```

Comment: This only works to return the pattern from a single row. The select needs to return the pattern for all rows that contain @SearchVal.

Comment: Why do you say it would only work for a single row? Instead of @TheString use the column in your table. Ohhh....I see what you mean. Give me a minute should be able to tweak this pretty easily.

Comment: Took me a while to wrap my mind around the logic of your solution but it does work. Seems like the number 100 could be replaced with len(SameVal) as well. Anyway, great solution. Thanks.

Comment: LOL oops. Yes the 100 should be replaced by len(SameVal). That was a placeholder while I put that together. ;)

Comment: IMHO one should never solve XML issues on string level. You might read my answer for some reasons...

Comment: @Shnugo I absolutely 1000000% agree. However it was not clear to me that they store actual xml. It just said they store xml tags as varchar. If the OP is really storing xml they should change the datatype and eliminate any suspicion about validity.

Comment: @Shnugo, I totally agree. However, we inherited the application this way. They XML code is stored in the table as varchar. No idea why but we have no choice but to manipulate as strings.

Comment: @DamnGenius *but we have no choice but to manipulate as strings* is not true. You can (and you should IMO) cast the string to XML and do your checkup with XML-methods. As explained in my answer there are many pitfalls on your route...

Answer (score 1):

Any interaction with XML should rely on the native XML methods SQL-Server provides. Dealing with XML on string level (with string methods like `CHARINDEX`, `SUBSTRING` etc) is erronous and might break with a slightly different but valid XML fragment. For example is the order of attributes not a part of the document. Blanks and line-breaks are introduced by the reader.

As example, your XML

```
<tag1><tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "fghij"></tag2></tag1>
```

can appear as

```
<tag1><tag2 value2='fghij' value1='abcde'/></tag1>
```

Both are semantically the same... String-methods would have to be very generic to deal with this...

The first thing was to use a natively typed XML column to store this value. This would avoid the `CAST(... AS XML)` in my query.

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(YourStringXML VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES 
 ('<tag1><tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "fghij"></tag2></tag1>')
,('<tag1><tag2 value1 = "hfdgd" value2 = "fgytyhij"></tag2></tag1>')
,('<tag1><tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "ettyy"></tag2></tag1>')
,('<tag1><tag2 value1 = "qwere" value2 = "mnbvb"></tag2></tag1>');

DECLARE @FindThisInValue1 VARCHAR(10) = 'abcde';

SELECT *
FROM @mockup m
WHERE CAST(YourStringXML AS XML).exist('/tag1/tag2[@value1=sql:variable("@FindThisInValue1")]')=1;
```

### Some explanation

The XML is `XQuering` the XML, if there is a `<tag2>` below `<tag1>` whith an attribute `value1` with a value like the sql-variable called `@FindThisInValue1`.

Assuming a native XML column this is pretty fast. Good to know: SQL-Server does not store the XML as the string you see, but as a hierarchically organised table in physical structures. `XPath` and `XQuery` can deal with this really well.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(400);
SET @Str = '<tag1><tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "fghij"></tag2></tag1>';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str, CHARINDEX('>', @Str) +1, CHARINDEX('/', @Str) - 8)
```

UPDATE:

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Str VARCHAR(400)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('<tag1><tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "fghij"></tag2></tag1>'),
('<tag1><tag2 value1 = "hfdgd" value2 = "fgytyhij"></tag2></tag1>'),
('<tag1><tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "ettyy"></tag2></tag1>'),
('<tag1><tag2 value1 = "qwere" value2 = "mnbvb"></tag2></tag1>');

SELECT SUBSTRING(Str, CHARINDEX('>', Str) +1, CHARINDEX('/', Str) - 8)
FROM T
WHERE Str LIKE '%"abcde"%';
--or more better
--WHERE Str LIKE '%value1 = "abcde"%';
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1874206c172bfd592456dd4fbb607d96)**

Comment: The select statement has to return the complete substring including the closest '<' and '>'. The result should be <tag2 value1 = "abcde" value2 = "fghij">

Comment: I now realize that I did not explain the issue clearly. I have updated the details above.

Comment: @DamnGenius I don't think that is hard to use it agaist your table, check the updates.

Comment: IMHO one should never solve XML issues on string level. You might read my answer for some reasons...